# Is there a book/film/videogame published by a major publisher that made use of WorldBuilding.SE?

Tags: discussion

According to Worldbuilding.SE's help:

> Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for developers, designers, writers and artists to get help creating imaginary worlds. This includes geography, culture and creatures for the world. Questions on this site should be about building settings and the reasons around why they are the way they are. A setting might not be a planet; it can be larger than a multiverse or smaller than a village.

Is there a widely published piece of work (e.g. a book with 1000+ copies sold) that made use of Worldbuilding.SE during the creative process?

Comment: I know this question isn't very well defined, but I hope people understand what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: As you only present a *single* example which mentions *selling*, can I assume that your question is excluding anything released for free?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T HPMOR would be a good example as well, even though it's free. Basically any major piece of work that has had enough readers.

Comment: @Secespitus yep, it's a dupe. And the answer seems to be a clear "no" :(

Comment: never heard of that abbreviation, sorry

Comment: Harry Potter and the methods of rationality.

Comment: Considering lead times for writing, submission, editing, and publishing, "not yet" is probably a better answer than "no".